# Windshield wiper hook arm equivalent sizes

Tags: windshield-wipers, fitment

Windshield wiper blades that fit hook arms often list various sizes for the hook: 1/2" &  3/4", 9x3 & 9x4, and 9mm. Are these all different sizes, or are any equivalent and, if so, which ones? More fundamentally, what do the sizes measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Windshield Wiper Guide](http://windshieldwiperguide.com/the-ultimate-windshield-wiper-blade-buyers-guide/#Attachment-systems) (which may not be the most credible), 9x4 is the same as 3/4", and 9x3 as 1/2". I was also able to put a blade that was supposed to fit both 3/4" and 1/2" hooks on a car that is listed as taking 9x3 blades.

From measuring a wiper blade, 9mm is the width of the hook, while 3/4" and 1/2" refer to the height of the hook.